# Selenium: checking for select options faster. C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to automate some data entry tasks for work.

Problem I'm having:
I need to check if a select (dropdown) has an option, and if so select it, otherwise continue.
The select has around 200 options which I didn't think was a lot but it seems to take a long time to go through the list and I'm wondering how I can speed it up.

I'm assuming its related to the type of objects the list is comprised of being beefy? (list of IWebElement)
Tried a basic for loop, as well as using the .Any method on the list, both seem equally unusually slow.

```
SelectElement brokeragePayeeOfficeSelect = new SelectElement(webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddBrokeragePayee")));
IList<IWebElement> officeOptions = brokeragePayeeOfficeSelect.Options;
bool result = officeOptions.Any(o => o.Text == brokerageOfficeArray[i]);
if (result)
{
     brokeragePayeeOfficeSelect.SelectByText(brokerageOfficeArray[i]);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing:" + brokerageOfficeArray[i]);
    continue;
}
```

The other option is to make the SelectElement.SelectByText method throw its exception faster.  Not sure how to do that.  Usually takes a minute or so for it to throw.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration with `Any` to check if the option is present is rather expensive. Instead try to select the option and catch the exception:

```
var brokeragePayeeOfficeSelect = new SelectElement(webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddBrokeragePayee")));

try {

    brokeragePayeeOfficeSelect.SelectByText(brokerageOfficeArray[i]);

} catch (NoSuchElementException) {

    Console.WriteLine("Missing:" + brokerageOfficeArray[i]);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but the timeout to throw the exception is a minute or two as well.  Doesn't really save any time.  Any ideas on how to make the exception throw faster? Is that possible?

Comment: You need to disable the implicit wait.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help.  I believe the default is 0 anyway.

Comment: A minute is way too much for `SelectByText`, especially if there's no implicit wait. It could be an issue with the document failing to reach a `complete` state. It could also be an issue with the XPath engine. It's hard to say without a reproducible example. Try to find a single `OPTION` with a CSS selector.

Comment: Giving you the answer.  For whatever reason the chromedriver seems to be running wayyyy faster now.  And the exceptions are being thrown within a second or two.  Must have been something wrong with my setup but I honestly have no idea what because I haven't changed anything!